# Replace all non-ASCII characters in a string by their ASCII equivalent

Tags: c++, string, qt

Using Qt/C++, I need to generate a string with only a subset of ASCII characters : letters, digits, hyphen, underscore, period, or colon.

As input, I can have anything.

So I try to apply some rules :

- every QChar::isSpace will be replaced with an underscore
- every non-ASCII letters will be replaced with an ASCII equivalent (example : "é"  will be replaced with "e")
- every other non-ASCII character will be removed

Is there any simple way with Qt/C++ to apply the 2nd and the 3rd rule ?

Thanks

Comment: If you can have anything as an input, what should be replacement for `嗨` character, for example?

Comment: This is possible, but you'd literally need to maintain a database mapping Unicode characters to what you think are their ANSI equivalents. Windows has an operating system API to do this, `WideCharToMultiByte`. I'm not sure if there is anything built into Qt; easy enough to tell by consulting the documentation. Generally the strategy is to replace "unknown" characters with a generic character, like that rectangular box or a simple question mark, instead of just removing them like your rule #3 suggests. But you can do whatever you want; generally the API takes a flag.

Comment: @vahancho : with the "simple" rules I plan to use, simply remove it. I you have a better option, I'm open !

Comment: @Cody Gray : maintaining such a database is what I try to avoid. And my application is multi-patform, so no Windows API call. If I don't find any better solution, I will use a replacement database.

Comment: Which ANSI character set?  Are you referring to ASCII perhaps?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'm reffering to ASCII. I update my question right now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.
At first you should do unicode normalization to your string with
`QString::normalized`. Normalization is needed to separate diacritical signs from letters and to replace some fancy symbols with ascii equivalents. [Here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) you can read about normalization forms.

Then you may take chars which can be encoded in Latin-1. Can be tested with
[toLatin1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html#toLatin1) method of QChar.

> **char QChar::toLatin1() const**
>
> Returns the Latin-1 character equivalent to the QChar, or 0. This is mainly useful for non-internationalized software.
>
> ...

```
QString testString = QString::fromUtf8("Ceñía-üÏÖ马克ñ");
QString normalized = testString.normalized(QString::NormalizationForm_KD);
QString result;

copy_if(normalized.begin(), normalized.end(), back_inserter(result), [](QChar& c) {
    return c.toLatin1() != 0;
});

qDebug() << result; // Cenia-uIOn
```